# Webpack how to call function in module after compiled

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, dynamics-crm

```
// helper.ts
export function GetMessage() {
    return "From helper";
}

// form.ts
namespace SDK.Test {
    export class Form {
        onLoad () {
            console.log(GetMessage());
        }  
    }
}
```

I'm using Typescript to organize Javascript code. The folder structure as follows

```
src
    --test
    ----form.ts
    ----helper.ts
```

each folder will be compiled into a single file by using entry property in webpack.config.js. It means that the above structure will be compiled into dist/test[.min].js. It does well. The problem is I don't know how to directly call the function like SDK.Test.Form.onLoad() because webpack produces some extra code as:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
....
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ({

/***/ "./src/test/form.ts":
/*!*******************************************!*\
  !*** ./src/test/form.ts ***!
  \*******************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var helper_1 = __webpack_require__(/*! ./helper */ "./src/test/helper.ts");
var SDK;
(function (SDK) {
    var Test;
    (function (Test) {
        var Form;
        (function (Form) {
            function onLoad() {
                console.log(helper_1.GetMessage());
            }
            Form.onLoad = onLoad;

        })(Form= Test.Form|| (Test.Form = {}));
    })(Test = SDK.Test|| (SDK.Test= {}));
})(SDK = exports.SDK || (exports.SDK = {}));


/***/ }),

/***/ "./src/test/helper.ts":
/*!*********************************************!*\
  !*** ./src/test/helper.ts ***!
  \*********************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
function GetMessage() {
    return "From helper";
}
exports.GetMessage = GetMessage;


/***/ })

/******/ });
//# sourceMappingURL=taitest.js.map
```

In the case of webpack cannot call directly, you have any recommend another way to call SDK.Test.Form.onLoad()?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that when you are referring to call `SDK.Test.Form.onLoad()`, you mean that you wanna call from the global scope.

You can use the `UMD` option of webpack + library.
That will expose a variable on the global scope of **the entry point export**.
For example:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  output: {
    library: 'myLib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    filename: 'myLib.js',
  }
};
```

This config, will expose myLib object (that its value is the export of the entry point) on the global scope.

For more info you can read: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-a-variable

Comment: I switched to rollupjs, by using webpack, we need to indicate global scope in ouput and if I have a lot of files, output will be grow unexpectedly. Thank @felixmosh